# Geolocation specific ASN

Tags: routing, router, ipv4, network, internet

question: is it possible to determine the geolocation of a city/region of a specific ASN?  For example, Telecom Italia has many ASNs.  Is it possible to know for each one "which soil" they cover?

Answer (score 2):

ASNs aren’t bound to a specific location, so what you’re asking is impossible to answer in general. Some large networks may use an ASN for a specific region, but if that’s the case you can only find out if they specified it some way, for example by giving it a name or description in WHOIS.